# IE11 and querySelector issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I got on my page inside a DIV with content editable on some text. In this text I need to get the value of all `P` elements (text written by user) but I need to exclude all span elements (variables that are not used for the rest of the work I have to do).

I tried to do it using querySelector in IE11 but here is the deal : For IE11 querySelector doesn't exist, even when I spy the element and it tell me this method exist (using F12 and putting a spy on it). What should I do to correct that ? I tried something I found on this forum that's say to put :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />
```

in the Head of the document, but it did not work.

The JS I use to do this is :

```
function recupTXT(div) {
  var textRecup = div.cloneNode(true);
  while (textRecup.querySelector("span") !== null) {
    textRecup.querySelector("span").parentNode.removeChild(textRecup.querySelector("span"));
  }
  return textRecup.innerText;
}
```

EDIT :

he is call like that :

```
var text = recupTXT(document.getElementById('edth_corps'));
```

where edth_corps is the content editable generated programmaticaly

If I try it on a stand alone, with the same condition (content editable and stuff), it work pretty fine and do what I need. But in my application it failed. So is it just a configuration issue ? or is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: You already mentioned X-UA-Compatible, but did you actually check what mode the browser is using? In IE devtools, go to Emulation tab; what does it say in Document Mode?

Comment: Document is 5 by default

Comment: Well, that's your problem then.

Comment: I changed it to IE10 but now the rest throw me some error before i reach this point

Comment: Change it to Edge, not IE10. (you'll probably still get the same error as IE10 mode, but Edge is IE11 mode, so you should stick with it as much as possible... as for the new error you're getting, you'll need to ask about that separately, but you should aim to fix it rather than going back to quirks mode). Also see below for my answer on how to avoid IE5 mode (Quirks Mode) in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stated that the `document mode is 5`.

This means that IE is running in Quirks Mode. This mode is designed to emulate IE5, and as a result it disables most of the browser features invented since IE5, including `querySelector`.

You can resolve the problem by preventing the browser from going into Quirks Mode.

This is achieved by making sure (1) that your HTML is valid, and (2) that it has a valid doctype declaration as the first line. If you don't have a doctype, add the following to the top of your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in that direction, my doctype is :
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >

Comment: Thanks a lot Simba, but know i have to go see my boss and tell them the webSite is so shitty it can't work above IE5 compatibility (it try it by changing the document type). So I guess i won't be staying long as an external ressources pointing out the failed of the regular employee.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like

```
var spans = textRecup.querySelectorAll("span");
for (var i=0;i<span.length;i++) {
  spans[i].parentNode.removeChild(spans[i]);
}
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("get").onclick = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById("cnt");
    var spans = div.querySelectorAll("span");
    for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
      spans[i].parentNode.removeChild(spans[i]);
    }
    console.log(div.innerHTML);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="cnt" contenteditable>

  <p>Here is some text and a <span>span</span> more text<br/>
    Here is some text and a <span>span</span> more text<br/>
    Here is some text and a <span>span</span> more text<br/>
    Here is some text and a <span>span</span> more text<br/></p>
  
</div>
<input type="button" id="get" value="get" />
```

Output in IE10 AND IE11 AND EDGE

[image]

Comment: because I got the same error : the object does not have the property or the method querySelectorAll. Even when I spy the object and see in his method that he got them.

Comment: already did and always get the same error message. For the Navigator the method querySelector and querySelectorAll does not exist for the object DispHTMLDivElement but when I look his methods I can see them

Comment: So the code here when you _run snippet_ gives you errors? Is your compatibility mode set in the browser settings perhaps?

Comment: your code works fine here, it's when I try it in my application that the errors appears

Comment: Then there is something else wrong obviously. So please post more code here or in a fiddle - what do you mean by application btw? HTA?

Comment: well all the function is here, and the JS does like 8K line so i won't be able to show it here. I can add the call of this function if it might help. what is HAT ?

Comment: @Slayner, then you need to break down the problem into a small reproducible case.

Comment: well it can be really smaller then that. I have another funtion that work to get the text but it is poorly written and really big because they just use For and whil again and again to go througth all the children node. I had the code use to call this function, and the fact that the content editable is generated programmaticaly

Comment: Btw if the intranet option for compatibilty isn't check the site does not work

Comment: Well then that sounds like a start.