# Javascript in IE 11 is running differently depending on where my file is located

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I have this JavaScript, with one problematic line (commented):

```
function createCheckboxes(allClasses) {
  var form = document.getElementById('showForm');
  var p = document.createElement('P');
  p.setAttribute('className','oneLine'); //Problematic line
  var text = document.createTextNode("All");
  var chkbox = document.createElement('INPUT');
  chkbox.type = 'checkbox';
  chkbox.id = 'ALL_BOX';
  p.appendChild(chkbox);
  p.appendChild(text);
  form.appendChild(p);

  for (var key in allClasses) {
    p = document.createElement('P');
    p.setAttribute('className','oneLine'); //problematic line
    text = document.createTextNode(key.replace(/_/g," "));
    chkbox = document.createElement('INPUT');
    chkbox.type = 'checkbox';
    p.appendChild(chkbox);
    p.appendChild(text);
    form.appendChild(p);
    chkbox.className = 'section';
    chkbox.id = key;
    if (allClasses[key]) {
      chkbox.checked = 'true';
    }
}
```

When I was executing this off of a shared (non-local) drive, the class was set successfully. But when I ran it off of my local drive, it did not set the class (tested doing `$('.oneLine').length()` )

I have fixed this using the "magic" of

```
  $(p).addClass('oneLine');
```

instead of setting the class in JavaScript. But I am stumped on how in the world javascript is seemingly processing the same code differently based on where the file originates. Understanding this would be really helpful to what I'm doing

Comment: Are you saying `p.setAttribute('className','oneLine');` worked when the file was executed off of a shared drive? If so, it is strange because it should never work... Are you able to reproduce that behavior consistently?

Comment: @acdcjunior yes it is replicated consistently. And I agree, it is strange... that's why I've posted my question here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I was looking for can be found here:[IE11 and querySelector issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088938/ie11-and-queryselector-issue)

It turns out that I needed the  tag to make both JavaScript and my CSS work consistently